# Removing specific html characters from a string

Tags: php

Its a bit tricky situation. I have a form for users to input their comments. Sometimes, users put in HTML characters. My problem is, I just want to save specific HTML characters like `bold, table, tr, td` with `<>` tags. Except this any other HTML characters should be removed from the string. I would like to know how to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[strip_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) allows you set list of  allowable tags.

> string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )

```
echo strip_tags($text, '<b><table><tr><td>');
```

Comment: I tried but it did not worked. My problem is that I am using tinymce editor to get user input. Somehow strip_tags is not working on the strings received from tinymce editor.